# Execute javascript inside the target of an Ajax Call Drag and Drop Shopping Cart without Server language

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Well i wanna create an Ajax Drag and Drop Shopping cart using only javascript and ajax. Currently i'm using the example in [this](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/drag-n-drop-shopping-cart-with-jquery-ui-tutorial/) page as a stepping stone. Right now it's only with local jquery and it works fine but i want to make the cart work with ajax calls. Note that i do not want to use a server side language( like php, rubby, asp etc), only html and javascript. 
My initial thought was that at the $(".basket").droppable i should add an ajax call to another html page containing the "server logic" in javascript, execute in that file all the necessary steps( like reading the get variables (product name, product id and quantity), set a cookie and then return an ok response back. When the server got the "ok" response it should "reload" the cart div with the updated info stored inside the cookie.

If this was with php i would know how to do it. The problem is that as far as i know, you can execute javascript once it reaches the DOM, **but how can you execute that js from inside the page that isbeing called upon ?** ( thanks to Amadan for the correction)
I've thought about loading the script using `$.getScript( "ajax/test.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr )..`  but the problem with that is that the url GET variables i want to pass to the "server script" do not exist in that page.

I havent implemented all the functionality yet as i am stuck in how to first achieve javascript  execution inside an ajax target page. 
Below is a very basic form of my logic so far

```
    // read GET variables
var product = getQueryVariable("product");
var id = getQueryVariable("id");
var quantity= getQueryVariable("quantity");    

//To DO 
//--- here eill go all the logic regarding cookie handling

function getQueryVariable(variable) {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if (pair[0] == variable) {
      return pair[1];
    }
  } 
  alert('Query Variable ' + variable + ' not found');
}
```

Any help regarding this matter will be appreciated.

Note: Logic in simple words: 
1)have an html page with products+cart
2)Have an "addtocart.html" with the "Cart Server Logic"( being the target of the ajax call when an item is dropped into the product.)

If you have some other idea on this, please enlighten me :)
thanks in advance

**Foot Note-1:**
if i try loading the scipt using

```
$("#response").load("ajax/addtocart.html?"+ $.param({
                    product: product,
                    id: id,
                    quantity:quantity
                    })
                );
```

i get the alert about not being able to find the url parameters( something that i thing is normal as because the content is being loaded into the initial page, from which the request is started, there are no get parameters in the url in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that as far as i know, you cannot execute javascript contained in the target of an ajax call, as that page never reaches the browser interpreter.

This is either incorrect or misleading. The browser will execute any JavaScript that enters DOM. Thus, you can use `$.load` to load content and execute code at the same time. Alternately, you can use hacked JSONP to both execute code and also provide content as a JSON document.

**EDIT**: Yes, you can't get to the AJAX parameters from JavaScript. Why do you want to? Do you have a good reason for it, or is it an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)?

The way I'd do it is this:

```
$('#response').load(url, data, function() {
  onAddedToCart(product, id, quantity);
});
```

and wrap your JS code in your HTML into the `onAddedToCart` function.

Depending on what exactly you're doing, it could be simplified even further, but this should be enough to cover your use case.

Comment: thanks for your reply :)
i've tried $("#response").load("ajax/addtocart.html?"+ $.param({
           product: product,
           id: id,
     quantity:quantity
     })
    );
but just like before it keeps triggering the alert ( cause in the initial page there are no get parameters. the get parameters are supposed to be in the ajax target html page.

Comment: i agree that the browser can execute any javascript loaded into the DOM. But how can i execute a javascript in the "Addtocart.html" page which receives the ajax request with the get parameters ?